# Ways to consume result from callable without blocking

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a class `A` which receives different independent tasks (all of which extends an abstract class `B` which implements Callable) from a listener, and assigns one thread to each task.. I would like to know if there exist patterns that are able to consume the results from these tasks without blocking the thread of class `A` such as what happens when using `submit()` with `Future.get()`.

The result I am looking for could be accomplished by appending the hypothetical consumer code to the task; however, within the foreseeable future, the code I wish to execute will be identical, and as I implement more tasks, my monkey brain will very likely forget to append the code a lot.

My current best potential solution is to just to have class `B` implement Runnable, put the consumer code in `run()` and task code in another method, and pass the parameters to the task through its constructor, which then saves them as class variables to be used when called. However, this pattern requires additional constructors, and some class variables that only really need to be local variables. Furthermore, with this method, I have encountered other problems such as NoSuchMethod exceptions when copying the tasks (I am using `.getClass().getConstructor(sth.class, sthelse.class).newInstance(sth, sthelse)`), even though I created the constructor.

So I am wondering if there are any other options.

Comment: Guava provides [`ListenableFuture`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html). You could also use [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), which was added in Java 8 (i.e. it's part of Java SE). If you need even more functionality you could look into a reactive library such as [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

Comment: Re, "The result I am looking for could be accomplished by appending the hypothetical consumer code to the task." If that works, then it's probably the right thing to do. Wrap the given `Callable`, `b`, in another `Callable`, `w`, and submit `w` to the executor. When `w` is called by the worker thread, it _directly_ calls `b`, and then does whatever needs to be done with the result.

Comment: I think CompletableFuture was what I was looking for. I now simply wrap the `Callable.call()` in a supplier and pass it to the future. In fact, I think I can actually wrap any plain method which returns a boolean into the supplier and get the same effect? Anyways, thank you both very much, @Slaw, @SolomonSlow